# gnu parallel --pipe producing empty output files

Tags: python, gnu-parallel

I'm struggling to try and run gnu parallel. I have a shell script that calls a python program several thousand times with different input params:

```
python /path/to/program/run.py A_02_01 input.fasta > /path/to/output/out.txt
python /path/to/program/run.py A_02_02 input.fasta > /path/to/output/out.txt
```

I tried using gnu parallel like so:

```
cat iedb_classi_call.sh  | parallel  --recstart 'python' --recend '\n' --pipe   bash
```

But all my output files are empty. I'm struggling to figure out why. I'm not getting errors from gnu parallel.

Before I added the recstart and recend options, I was getting non-empty output files for some python calls, but other program calls weren't executing and getting errors like:

```
run.py: error: incorrect number of arguments
bash: line 422: 01_ input.fasta: command not found
Usage: run.py allele fasta_file
```

Which made me think parallel was reading in chunks not separated properly and I added the --recstart / --recend parameters to parallel

I'm using gnu parallel version 20180722

Comment: Ugh! What parameters do you need to run with - I mean where are they?

Comment: Why don't you put a shebang at the start of the Python script and make it executable so you don't need to keep typing `python` to run it?

Comment: NVM - I was misunderstanding how to use parallel. I just wrote a wrapper script to generate calls with needed parameters  to my program then just piped it to parallel. It seems to be working: ```generate-runs.sh | parallel ```

Comment: In your example the output file is named the same. If that is correct, then that will explain why it is empty. The output files must have different names.

Answer (score 0):

(This should be a comment as it does not answer the actual question, but formatting code does not work very well).

If the lines are like:

```
python /path/to/program/run.py A_02_01 input.fasta > /path/to/output/out.txt
python /path/to/program/run.py A_02_02 input.fasta > /path/to/output/out.txt
```

Then you might be able to do:

```
cat file-with-A_names |
  parallel --results /path/{}.out python /path/to/program/run.py {} input.fasta >/dev/null
```

The output will be stored in `/path/A....out`.